# How to make a partially inline Bootstrap form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to produce this form with Bootstrap 3:

[image]

I'm having trouble making First Name and Last Name inline AND making them together take up the same width as the other fields. Currently I have the following

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Administrator</h4>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="Email Address" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

which outputs a simple form with no inlining. Any ideas how to adjust this to look like in the picture? Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gJdyb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJdyb/3/). Use class `row` on the `form-group` you'd like to inline:

Administrator

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="Email Address" />
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but, it doesn't seem to work. The First Name and Last Name fields are now really small. I see this: http://chadjohnson.io/static/how-to-make-a-partially-inline-boostrap-form.png

Comment: To increase the size of the fields, you just need to increase the width of the columns. eg, I changed col-md-6 on the parent div to col-md-12, and made col-md-3 on the input divs col-md-6. Now they line up.

Comment: Awesome. That worked -- thanks. Don't know why I didn't think of wrapping the individual inputs with half the col size. BTW, I simplified your jsFiddle, removing some divs: http://jsfiddle.net/gJdyb/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Administrator</h4>


    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="Form-group">

            <input type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="Email Address" />

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gJdyb/4/

it use the col-xs-6.. it is us

read this for documentation of grid system of bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid